# How to add scrolling ability in console application for display of larger input?

Tags: c++, unix, console-application

I am building a project that requires me to read matrices from a given `.txt` file, process it (row addition) and then display it on console (I am required to show the file contents).

The program works fine, given, the matrix length is small, however when it goes to lets say `200 x 200`, that is where the problem arises.

How can I add a scrollbar for `left/right` and make the console window auto adjust to the size of text?

Also I am on macOS and would rather like a solution that also works on windows and that is, where my project is going to be evaluated at!

Answer (score 1):

[Pipe the output to a program](https://www.unix.com/302195143-post2.html?s=c950c7aa5b29d10695073c9dda07fa7b) that implements the scrolling for you. I used `less -S`, since `less` allows me to scroll in all directions.

There are probably more "native" solutions e.g. [ncurses](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses), if you prefer to roll your own.